# passing nested JSON data from mongoose model is not working

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am pushing nested JSON data to database. This is how my schema looks like,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// original Schema

const dataSourceSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
    config:{type: String, required: true}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('DataSource', dataSourceSchema);
```

I would like to pass the following json data to my dataSourceSchema,

```
{
“name”:”JdbcSourceConnector”,
"type" :"string",
“config”: {
“connector.class”:” io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector”,
“tasks.max”:1,
“connection.url”:”<connection to connect to database along with username and password>”,
“mode”:”incrementing”,
“incrementing.column.name”:”<incrementing column name in table>”,
“topic.prefix”:”test-mysql-jdbc-”
}
}
```

But its not taking, gives casting error or ',' expected.

So i tried this,

```
const dataSourceSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
    config:{ 
    connector.class:{ type: String, required: true },
tasks.max:{ type: String, required: true },
connection.url:{ type: String, required: true },
mode:{ type: String, required: true },
incrementing.column.name:{ type: String, required: true },
topic.prefix:{ type: String, required: true }
}

});
```

this Schema is also giving me errors, ',' expected.

If i pass just a string as i have mentioned in my original schema, the data gets stored in db.
but i want to pass the nested json data, please guide me in right direction.
I also tried `stringify` the data , its not working.

Comment: You are using `“`  which is a special character, use `"`

Comment: To avoid casting error, use `Schema.Types.Mixed` instead of `String` for config like  `config:{type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true}`

Comment: Thanks Arifkhan, I ll try this.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it , the error lies in defining you schema with your second schema you came close to the answer. Change you schema as follows:

```
const dataSourceSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
      type: { type: String, required: true },
      projectId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project', required: true },
      config:{ 
            connectorClass:{ type: String, required: true },
            tasksMax:{ type: String, required: true },
            connectionUrl:{ type: String, required: true },
            mode:{ type: String, required: true },
            incrementingColumnName:{ type: String, required: true },
            topicPrefix:{ type: String, required: true }
      }
});
```

I have suggested the change as mongoose doesn't understand the dot notation in the key column of it's schema, hence you were receiving the error you have mentioned.

If you want to use the dot notation for some reason encapsulate the key in " and not in the special character as appearing in your code snippet.

P.s. - Don't forget to change the key names in your json

Comment: Thanks aashisAilawadi, I want to pass with dot(.) in my json data.  could you please help me to parse the data with (.) in data.

Comment: @darshanan As I can see you are using the character “ instead of  the regular ". I would suggest you to retype the double quotes in your editor again and check wether they are the standard double  quotes or not.